# MsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx and alertable wait state

Tags: winapi

Is it possible to enter an alertable wait state using `MsgWaitForMultipleObjects()` / `MsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx()`?

Answer (score 2):

it is possible to enter into an alertable wait if you specify MWMO_ALERTABLE flag as the last parameter (dwFlags - the wait type)

Answer (score 0):

`MsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx` puts the thread in an alertable wait state.

From MSDN on [SleepEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686307.aspx):

> A thread goes into an alertable wait state by calling either SleepEx, MsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx, WaitForSingleObjectEx, or WaitForMultipleObjectsEx, with the function's bAlertable parameter set to TRUE.

Comment: Yeah, but MsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx doesn't have a bAlertable parameter. Does it just go into alertable state by default?

Comment: @Ee Zz: To expand on that, the only difference (as far as I am aware) between MsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx and MsgWaitForMultipleObjects is the former is alterable, thus no separate parameter or flag is needed.